# JEST Express Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am facing an error using JEST with Express while I execute my test with `npm run test`.

```
  console.error
    Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden
```

I've seen similar post like [CORS error - Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785617/cors-error-error-cross-origin-http-localhost-forbidden-in-reactjs-jest-te) without working answers

Here is my test  :

```
const app = require('../app');
const request = require("supertest");
const enjoyService = require('../services/enjoy.service');

describe('/enjoy', () => {
    describe("/cinema/:city", () => {
        test('Status is OK', () => {
            return enjoyService.listCinema("nantes").then(res => {
                expect(res.data.status).toBe('OK');
            });
        });
        test('Status is 404', () => {
            return enjoyService.listCinema("X Æ A-XII").catch(err => {
                expect(err.name).toBe("Error");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And the `enjoy.service` used bellow

```
const axios = require('axios'),
    googleBaseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=";

function listCinema(city) {
    return axios.get(googleBaseURL + city + '&type=cinema&key=' + process.env.GOOGLE_API)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a [similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1418). It could help someone else having the same issue using **JEST** and **ExpressJS**

The similar issue says we have to add to our **jest.config.js**

```
{
  // ...
  testEnvironment: 'node'
  // ...
}
```

In my case I added the code bellow to my `package.json` like so

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
```

**Good to know** if you want to add the config from your `package.json` like me

> If you'd like to use your package.json to store Jest's config, the
> "jest" key should be used on the top level so Jest will know how to
> find your settings:
>
> ```
> {
>  "name": "my-project",
>  "jest": {
>    "verbose": true
>  }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to fix this problem by adding this validation snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios'

if(typeof process != 'undefined'){
  axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
}

/.../
```

Comment: For those with stricter, modern TS requirements, add the following to a .d.ts file: `declare module 'axios/lib/adapters/http';` and modify William's answer to use `axios.defaults.adapter = (await import('axios/lib/adapters/http')).default;`

Answer (score 2):

**More local solution**

Instead of changing the test environment globally to make one test work, you could change the test environment or even single environment options for that particular test only by adding a docblock at the top of the test file.

See the docs for further information: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironmentoptions-object

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment-options {"url": "http://other-than-localhost"}
 */
```

Comment: This could also work for a file: `/** @jest-environment node */`